# Por que o texto do Widget Button sempre fica em caixa-alta quando inserido?

Tags: android, android-layout

Estou criando uma IU programaticamente e sempre que insiro o texto nos botões com setText(), o texto fica em caixa-alta. Na IU feita com xml a mesma coisa acontece. Gostaria que IU mantivesse o texto como foi inserido. Maiúsculo como maiúsculo e minúsculo como minúsculo.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use um atributo `textAllCaps` como `false`

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente. Obrigado. Também encontrei o metodo setAllCaps() para usar programaticamente.